# Adding Pop-Up Dialog to ListView Adapter Android

Tags: android

I am new to coding and am looking to add a pop-up view into my code but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a listview that is using a JSON parse to obtain a bunch of names and put them into my listview. What I am trying to do is click on the names, for instance list item #4 has the name "Bob", and when I click on Bob I want a pop-up to show up with some information I already made in an XML. I can get it to work as an intent, which I have posted my working code from my
`Adapter class` 
below, but I want to change it from an intent and make it a pop-up dialog instead. Can anyone help me please?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());

    //listen for item click then open new activity
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CoinDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("banana", listItem.getHead());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewHead;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

Define this methode on your Activity,

```
public void showDialog(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("a title");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

And inside onclick :

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((ActivityName)context).showDialog("the message you want to show");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both methods, both crashed my app. The first method was giving me an error at the alertdialog.show and the second method gave me an error at the Layout Inflator.

Comment: What's the name of your activity wich contains the recyclerView?

Comment: See the updated code, replace `ActivityName` with your actual acivity name

Comment: Still does not work. I defined the main method but was getting an error when using "this" and also inside click could not use the `MyAdapter` as my activity. I tried to put the main method into my Main Activity and it got rid of the this error and left the inside click in my adapter class and used `MainActivty` instead but I am still getting an app crash on insideclick.